# How to prevent VS Code from wrapping HTML tag content

Tags: html, angular, visual-studio-code

`"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned"` worked perfectly, it touched tag attributes and was doing nothing to tag content (I'm writing in Angular so its perfect for me) until today. Content started to wrap in places I don't want it to wrap in, I just want it to be preserved as it is. Everywhere. `"html.format.wrapLineLength": 0` isn't helping, as so `html.format.contentUnformatted` doesn't (when I start to add some tags there - everything breaks). I need a solution for this.

I'm using `"editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"`

Ternary operators are formatted from:

```
 <span>
      {{
        isTrue 
          ? 'Yes'
          : 'No'
      }}
 </span>
```

To

```
      <span>
    {{
    isTrue
    ? 'Yes'
    : 'No'
    }}
</span>
```

And yes, that's how it really is in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"html.format.templating": true,` solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

There were a couple things I had to change in order to get this to work properly for me (for HTML-specific files):

1. Set `HTML > Format: Wrap Line Length` to 0. Setting this to 0 disables how many characters you can have on a single line before wrapping begins. Alternatively, you can set this to an amount you wish to enforce any single line to not exceed.
2. Set `HTML > Format: Wrap Attributes` to `preserve-aligned`.